# Pygame TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, typeerror

This few lines of python 3.2 code uses the latest pygame module to move an image. It is related to this example:
http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/MoveIt.html

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import sys 

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400))
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')
player = pygame.image.load('player.jpg')
pos = player.get_rect()

while True:
    for i in pygame.event.get():
       if i.type() == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
    screen.blit(player,(i,i))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Here is the error I get when running it:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:/Users/Grounds Keeper Willy/Desktop/Python Code/test.py", line 12, in 
>      if i.type() == pygame.QUIT:
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

I have found similar questions but the answers stated that the problem was using a function name as a variable too, which is not what I'm doing. I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should read:

```
if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

instead of:

```
if i.type() == pygame.QUIT:
```

since the `type` member of the `Event` class is not a function, so you don't need/can call it by using `()`.